# Clearing TreeView item ChildNodes also clears Parent reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm developing an ASP.NET 4.0 web application and I am using a TreeView control. I have one problem that I really can't understand why this is happening. I have checkboxes associated with the tree items.

If the checkbox is not checked everything works just fine, but when I execute the following line:

```
node.ChildNodes.Clear();
```

If the checkbox is checked for the node, the node.Parent is null after the Clear(). If it is not checked, parent is still correct. I really can't understand why the clearing of the childnodes collection will also clear my parent reference. I actually don't use or modify the checked property within this call. I am also 100% sure that my parent isn't a child to my node as well (why would it differ if it checked or not).

The workaround I need to use in order for the code to work as expected is:

```
TreeNode[] checkedNodes = new TreeNode[tvResults.CheckedNodes.Count];
tvResults.CheckedNodes.CopyTo(checkedNodes, 0);
foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes) // Uncheck all nodes temporary.
    checkedNode.Checked = false;

node.ChildNodes.Clear(); // Now it is ok to clear and parent is "saved".

foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes) // Recheck all checked nodes again.
    checkedNode.Checked = true;
```

Any idea anyone about this issue?

Thanks,
Mattias

PS! Please be kind, this is my first question ever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code from ASP.NET `TreeNodeCollection.Clear` (from .NET 4.5). As you can see, it does clear all checked nodes without performing any validation. So this is by design (rather a bug by design) and not a bug in your code. My advice would be add an extension method that performs the workaround you listed in the question so that you can easily reuse it.

```
// System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeCollection
/// <summary>Empties the <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeCollection" /> object.</summary>
public void Clear()
{
if (this.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}
if (this._owner != null)
{
    TreeView owner = this._owner.Owner;
    if (owner != null)
    {
        if (owner.CheckedNodes.Count != 0)
        {
            owner.CheckedNodes.Clear();
        }
        for (TreeNode treeNode = owner.SelectedNode; treeNode != null; treeNode = treeNode.Parent)
        {
            if (this.Contains(treeNode))
            {
                owner.SetSelectedNode(null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach (TreeNode current in this._list)
{
    current.SetParent(null);
}
this._list.Clear();
this._version++;
if (this._isTrackingViewState)
{
    this.Log.Clear();
}
this.Log.Add(new TreeNodeCollection.LogItem(TreeNodeCollection.LogItemType.Clear, 0, this._isTrackingViewState));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a bit of unexpect behaviour, but it explains what happens.